# C Beginner: Multiplication table

Tags: c, for-loop, nested-loops, multiplication

I'm new to C and I'm trying to create a simple multiplication table with size based on user input, but I'm having some issues with the output.

How can I make my table include the row and column for number 1?

```c
void main()
{
  int j,i,n;
  printf("Enter the size from 1-10: ");
  scanf("%d",&n);
    
  for (i=1; i<=10; i++)
  {
    for (j=1; j<=n; j++)
    {
      if (j <= n-1)
        printf("%d\t",i*j);
      else
        printf("%d\t",i*j);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```

Current output:

```
1       2       3       4       5
2       4       6       8       10
3       6       9       12      15
4       8       12      16      20
5       10      15      20      25
6       12      18      24      30
7       14      21      28      35
8       16      24      32      40
9       18      27      36      45
10      20      30      40      50
```

EDIT:
Sorry for writing my question in haste. I want my output to look something like this:

[image: Desired output]

Comment: Please [edit] and show the desired output instead of only describing it.

Comment: You can print the column labels (all of them) before the first `for` loop and the row label (single) before the second `for` loop.

Comment: @FiddlingBits but what would those column and line labels be??

Comment: @Jabberwocky Would they not be the Multiplier and Multiplicand?

Comment: I think that was a joke.

Comment: @FiddlingBits but they are already there. I don't understand what the OP wants.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I got you.  I guess I don't either.

Comment: Sorry for writing my question in haste. I want my output to look something like this: https://ibb.co/dkyZcpX

The main issue is I dont understand how to include the print for 1*1, 1*2, 1*3 etc. Please note that I'm a total beginner and it might be a really simple solution to this..

Comment: Thank you for the clarification, but please don't post pictures of text, but post text as text. What you want to do is pretty simple, why don't you try it on your own first, and then maybe ask  a question?

Comment: @Jabberwocky Gotcha. I've tried to solve it for a while now but I'm stuck. I'm pretty sure I need to add some extra prints, one outside the loops and one inside the first loop maybe? But I'm not sure what the print should include. Would appreciate a solution with explanation.

Comment: It's really simple: print the first line `x  |   1  2  3 ... `, a printf and a simple loop. Then print the `"------"` line. The for each line you print, print `"  x  | "` beforehand. Use the `"%5d"` format specifier which will print the number correctly aligned with spaces. Give it a try and then ask questions about your possibly failing code

Comment: Thanks, I got the first part done now. For the left side header, when I put `printf( " x  | ");` inside the outer loop it just prints x on the beginning of each row. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Cero14 show your code. Possibly ask a new specific question about that.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Yay I made it. Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I worked on your problem and finally create the output that you wanted.
Code is [here](https://github.com/Lovish-Garg/PracticeC/blob/main/Data%20Structures/Arrays/Num%20Arrays/CreateTable.c).

- So I have done that before printing each character I'm checking the
  length of the number and according to that I'm printing the number.
- I do the best approach I can do and it does give desire output.

[EDITED] : I have updated my code. There was some problem with small numbers ,So try it again  on the old link.

Comment: You could simplify by using the "%5d" (or similar) format specifier, which will take care of the extra spaces. Also you should post your cod ehere and not in an external link

Comment: Sorry I forgot about that.

Comment: But even then following your approach jabber I need to found the length of number and instead of your numbers after %d I have use spaces but at least I code the problem and it does give desire output.

Comment: BTW the output is not quite correct, but you're almost there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225480/discussion-between-lovish-garg-and-jabberwocky).

Comment: @LovishGarg Thanks for a clean solution. It's a bit overkill for me since I just started with C this week, I haven't learned about switch case yet. But I appreciate the help.

Comment: Cero I would suggest you not make such programs because as you said they are a bit overkill for you . You should solve logic problems from websites and then in between make some of your own programs like this one. In this way you can also improve your knowledge about C and also build up logic side by side.

Comment: @Cero14 If you have got the result you wanted you should upvote or mark the answer with green tick. This shows that the question has been answered and it is also a way to thanks to the person who gave you answer.